# (Bullets Physics) How to avoid tunneling with compound shapes resembling rings?

Tags: shapes, tunneling, bulletphysics

I've got some compound shapes built from four rectangular shapes resembling a squared frame, the idea is to use them as rough aproximations of rings

The rings are tossed around pegs, and several rings can be tossed simultaneously, tough ring collide with each other some times, they must not get stuck as chains

They get stuck due to tunneling, as is shown on the following images

Is there a way to avoid this "chaining" effect due to tunneling?

[image: Compound Ring]

a) compound body, b) individual shapes, and c) top view

[image: Tunneling effect]

Comment: Do you a have a screenshot? Have you made chain from these frames?

Comment: No, my intention is not to make a chain... it's to make rings, that move around and eventually could collide with each other, though more often than not they get stuck as chains, think on a couple of kids throwing hulahoops at each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply just use a cylinder or box as your ring proxy? Do you really need things to be able to move through the center of the rings without collision?

A solid box volume should still roughly approximate your ring, but should be far easier to resolve tunneling issues for.

Comment: using a cylinder cold do the job, if it weren't that they need to get "trapped" by pegs... as in a ring toss game, I've updated my question to be more specific, I hope

Comment: Could you use two separate proxies? Use your 4 boxes for collisions with the pegs, and use cylinders for collisions between rings.

Comment: Maybe that could work, I think Bullets Physics can't filter collisions that way, but I can try a custom listener, to se if there is performance penalties